# Install the libjackpal-androidterm4.so in /system/lib

Tags: android, eclipse, terminal, emulation

I'm trying to run the Android Terminal Emulator (ATE) in Eclipse and error shows about UnsatisfiedLinkError. According to what I read it's because of the .so file that is not installed in the /system/lib and in order to have that, you need to unzip and get the .so from the .apk file. I'm already done getting the .so file, My problem now is how to install the libjackpal-androidterm4.so in system/lib? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to root your device to put so files there. However I think you do something wrong. Do some research how to work with the NDK and how to deliver so files.

Comment: I've already done copying the lib with the .so file folder in the app's package and there are 3 folders inside, armeabi,mips,x86. I don't know what kind of code will I make inside the make file.

Comment: The target platform must match the its directory name. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

If running in eclipse 
Run>Run Configuration>select your project>click "Arguments" tab>
In "VM arguments"  put "-Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir/that/conintains/so/files"

Try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dir/that/conintains/so/files
```

and than run your java application.

Or

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir/that/conintains/so/files com.company.Main
```

Comment: There's no such tab as Arguments, only Android, Target and Common.

Comment: -Djava.library.path=D:\New folder\Android-Terminal-Emulator-master\lib\armeabi Is this correct? If it is, it's still the same, the app forces close.